# Contractive Property and Continuous Bijections

Tags: general-topology

Let (X,T) be a topological space and P any topological property. P is said to be a contractive  topological property if   (X,T) has that property then any topology weaker than T also has that property.
How can we prove that a topological property is contractive if and only if it is preserved under continuous bijections.?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Let $\tau$ and $\tau'$ be topologies on $X$. Show that the identity map from $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ to $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ is continuous if and only if $\tau'\subseteq\tau$.

Answer (score 0):

The hint of **Brian** enables you to prove that the condition is sufficient.

Conversely 
let topological space $X=\langle\left|X\right|,\tau\rangle$ have
a contractive topological property $P$.

Let $Y=\langle\left|Y\right|,\tau_{Y}\rangle$ denote a topological
space and let $f:X\to Y$ denote a continuous bijection.

It is our aim to prove that also $Y$ has the property.

Defining $\tau':=\left\{ f^{-1}\left(U\right)\mid U\in\tau_{Y}\right\} $
we have $\tau'\subseteq\tau$ and it can be shown easily that $\tau'$
is a topology on $\left|X\right|$.

Then topological space $X':=\langle\left|X\right|,\tau'\rangle$ will
have the property.

Now prescribe $g:X'\to Y$ by $x\mapsto f\left(x\right)$.

It can be shown that $g$ is a homeomorphism and [topological properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_property) are
preserved under homeomorphisms, so we are allowed to conclude that also $Y$ has the property.